# How to use a table column in my select box on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select

I'm trying to create a select box that takes data from my db.  I'm having trouble setting this up.  I tried this code:

```
<%= f.fields_for :unit do |u| %>
  <%= u.label :name %>
  <%= u.select :name, :class => "ingredient_unit", :prompt => "Please Select" %>
<% end %>
```

but I'm missing the part of the choices, I don't know how to pull them out of the database.  I tried using collection_select, which worked, but then the class option wasn't working... collection_select went like this:

```
<%= u.collection_select :unit, Unit.all, :id, :name, :class => "ingredient_unit", :prompt => "Please Select" %>
```

I also don't understand what the first symbol means (:unit), it seems to be setting the html id and name, so that can be anything I want it to be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look at the documentation for [collection_select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select) and [select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select). But to answer your question, for the select part, you forgot to pass the list of options to choose from.  You also need to swap the order for `prompt` and `class` since `prompt` is an option for the helper and `class` is an html option

```
<%= u.select :unit_id, Unit.all.map { |u| [u.name, u.id] }, { :prompt => "Please Select" }, { :class => "ingredient_unit" } %>
```

For the collection select

```
<%= u.collection_select :unit_id, Unit.all, :id, :name, { :prompt => "Please Select" }, { :class => "ingredient_unit" } %>
```

The first parameter passed to both helper is the column name where you want the selected answer to be saved.  The 2 codes above just shows 2 different ways to generate the same select tag.

Comment: Copy pasting your first one, I get an error `{:class=>"ingredient_unit"} is not a symbol`, if I remove the curly brackets form prompt I get a syntax error on class, and if i remove all the curly brackets, i get a wrong number of arguments 3 of 4.  I'm looking straight at the docs and read it a number of times but I can't get this to work...  The collection_select works, but I can't set the class

Comment: that's weird. I don't see anything wrong with my code. The `collection_select` should also work fine. This is weird.

Comment: sorry the collection_select actually does work (I had to put prompt within a hash too), the other regular select doesn't work though.

Comment: can you paste the stack trace in a gist?

Comment: nevermind, i was trying to get you the stack trace and it actually did work :), thanks!  Can you also update your answer to include the answer to my question about what the first symbol represents so i can select it as best... i have been reading the docs but i'm a little lost because both select and collection_select take the same first 2 arguments, but they are clealry not the same in your answer

Comment: Done.  I'd like to clarify that they should be the same.  Without knowing where you're using this form, I can only guess the column name  so I placed in 2 different values.  I changed it to the more meaningful and logical name of the column, `unit_id`

Answer (score 2):

The first symbol tells it which field to populate with the id returned from the user selection.

Also, you should wrap your class section in {}

Comment: sorry you're answer is pretty much the same as the one above haha, but I'll post the same question for you here, the field i want to populate is in another table called entry_ingredients and the field is `:unit_id` as its the foreign key.  How would I set that up, because according to what you said my code is clearly wrong

Comment: You tell it which field you want to populate, followed by the table you want to pull the options from such as `EntryIngredient.all`, then you tell it the id field, then the one you want to use to display the text such as :id, :ingredient.

You end up with `u.collection_select :ingredient_id, EntryIngredient.all, :id, :ingredient`

Comment: No no, what I'm saying is that the field I want to populate is on a different table than the fields I'm populating from.  So I want the id to be set in entry_ingredients for unit_id, but I want to get the data from table units from name.

Comment: OK, well I'm not sure how you would do that.

Answer (score 2):

`:unit` refers to the model attribute that you're using for the select element. Yes, it will setup the name/id of the element (and name is the most important for the params hash).

To set a class in the collection_select, specify it as a hash as that helper takes it as an html_option.

```
<%= u.collection_select :unit, Unit.all, :id, :name, { :prompt => "Please Select" }, { :class => "ingredient_unit" } %>
```

Comment: it gave me a syntax error wrapping it in {} `syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting tASSOC
...:class => "ingredient_unit"} );`

Comment: if the first symbol refers to the model attribute that I'm using for the select, its actually on another table called entry_ingredients and the attribute is :unit_id, how would I set that up?  or would I just put `:unit_id` and rails would know what to do because of my associations?

Comment: ok it works now, I had to put the prompt within a hash as well for it to work with collection_select, but I can't see why the regular select doesn't work